# Acer Nitro 5 AN515-44-R11B, Ubuntu doesnt recognize drivers and second monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

So when i run nvidia-xconfig, the system says:
[image: 1]

I don't know how to fix that and i think that this is what cause to my second monitor just stay in power mode, weeks ago was working perfectly and works just fine on win 11, but on ubuntu doesn't, and if i go on the Additional Drivers tab and select the noveau graphics the second monitor shows but with some white stripes on it.

I've followed the guide on the [link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7) and didn't have any success.

Comment: So for anyone who is having the same problem, the solution for me was going into BIOS setup and disable the Secure Boot option

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want the nvidia drivers installed, you should stick to Ubuntu's Hardware Tab in its settings. There are many descriptions in this forum on how to install an Nvidia driver. What you shouldn't do: Downloading any drivers from somewhere else. Please state your Ubuntu version in your question

Comment: Addition to @kanehekili, paste an output of nvidia-driver version and `xrandr`

Comment: i've been managed to fix it, it was because secure boot was seeing the nvidia driver as not official, even when select in Software & Updates/ Additional Driver on ubuntu, i didnt downloaded any driver on internet, just the options that ubuntu showed!